# how to create dialogs like apprequest dialog from hackbook for Android

Tags: android, dialog, facebook-app-requests

I am trying to create a customized dialog with a lot of resources like apprequest dialog from hackbook for android.

there is nothing similar @  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. Someone knows how to do it?

Tnx in advance

[image]

Comment: what you have tried? `Dialog` have a method `setContentView(...)` you can set any content view to your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To create a customized dialog like the one we have in our SDK, its simply a custom class extending `Dialog`, which you can read up on in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).

Facebook's Android SDK is open sourced on github, and [this file](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/FbDialog.java) shows you how we generate the custom dialog for our purposes.  If you dig through the source code you see that we're actually loading a `WebView` for the content inside the dialog, but you can always create your own native layout and set it with `setContentView()`.  Let me know if that helps!

-Jesse

Comment: I got it. tnx! [tutorial: how to display a custom dialog in android app](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)